# How to get routes for devise passwords page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Been trying to get the route for the devise passwords page on a rails app using

```
devise_for :users, path_names: {
    password: 'secret'
}
```

But it isn't returning it, any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify what the passwords page is?  I'm not sure I understand what's page you're asking for.  Classic the devise URLs will all be in the format `[action]_user_session_url`

Comment: Run `rake routes` on the command line; that may lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Im trying to generate routes for 
devise/paswords/new
devise/passwords/edit. When i rake the routes they dont show up

Answer (score 0):

```
rake routes
```

will run all routes available from devise. If you want to access devises password options (IE edit password, confirm password, enter password etc) go to devise, resources, edit and look for the form_for. You can actually use these resources and add your own to multiple views. Quoting directly from devises github on this..

By default, Devise allows users to change their password using the `:registerable` module. But sometimes, developers want to create other actions that allow the user to change their information without requiring a password. The best option in this case is to create your own controller, that belongs to your application, and provide an edit and update actions, as you would do for any other resource in your application.

Keep in mind though to be restrictive in the parameters you allow to be changed. In particular, you likely want to permit just user data fields and avoid e-mail, password and such information to be changed:

```
params[:user].permit(:first_name, :last_name, :address)
```

An alternative solution would be to simply override "update resource" method in your registrations controller as follows:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  protected

  def update_resource(resource, params)
    resource.update_without_password(params)
  end
end
```

When using this solution you will need to tell devise to use your controller in routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'registrations'}
```

Finally, if you have generated views using devise, remove the corresponding form input for 'current_password' in `app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb`.